# Некоторые случаи употребления тире

Tags: пунктуация

Володь, когда сможем встретиться напишу - чтоб добить тему, сейчас я занят. 
За полдня, за день напишу - устроит?

Подскажите, господа, всё ли здесь верно, что касается пунктуации? В особенности меня интересует тире. Почему они поставлены, на каком основании?
Перед "сейчас я занят" возможна постановка двоеточия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Володь, когда сможем встретиться, напишу (чтоб добить тему), сейчас я занят. За полдня, за день напишу — устроит?***

Запись разговорной речи, упрощенные знаки препинания.

Первое тире надо заменить скобками, а то получается: напишу, чтобы добить тему. Вероятно, они встретятся, чтобы "добить тему".

В упрощенном варианте значение причины не обозначается двоеточием, ставится запятая (второе предложение распространяет первое).

Второе тире на месте. Это БСП, но оба предложения неполные, структура разная. (За полдня, за день напишу — тебя это устроит?)

Comment: А если бы конструкция была такова. Володя, напишу, когда сможем встретиться - чтоб добить тему. Если тире в таком случае возможно, то на каком основании?

Comment: Вообще по грамматике здесь основным знаком является  запятая, а тире - авторский знак, обозначающий добавочный характер сообщения.